# jquery mobile: pagebeforechange does not fire until next page "loads"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile (1.3.2) without ajax (`$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;`) and jquery (1.9.1). I want to show a page-loading-image **before** the user gets to the next page. Therefore I used the folowing code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange',function(e,data){
   $('#loading_image').show();
});

$(window).load(function(){
   $('#loading_image').fadeOut(100);
});
```

The problem is, that when I click on a link first the new site loads and after that the `pagebeforechange`-event fires. You can see that on http://m.alstaetter-tc.de . Does anyone have an idea what to do to get the `pagebeforechange`-event fire before the next page appears?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for is inbuilt in jQ M

Just enable the ajax :)

Comment: pls elaborate on your answer.

Comment: I don´t want to use Ajax... I think there must be another opportunity.